# smart contract use case: secure validator

Tags: contract-development

I have almost no experience with blockchains & smart contracts, but quite much in coding generally.

Solving a data verification problem for new product we're developing.

The question is quite abstract:
Suppose, we have incoming data from multiple external internet devices signed by their private keys. We need to:

1. verify the data by using the respective public key
2. sign the data by additional private key (one for all)
3. send the data further (outside of blockchain)

Does it make sense to use smart contracts for it, or having our secure dedicated verification server is a better option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood your question, instead of having a server , you are going to use an ethereum network and smart contract to do the processing of data verification of real-time coming data and pass it along.

Since it seems like just data processing and there will be no value for the transaction sent after the data is processed and returned (i.e. no later auditing) and there will be no economical benefit by tokens or some other means( like you are gonna take some fee by ETH for verification process) , as per my knowledge its better to go with a client server architecture. (because sending transactions is costly to users and running nodes will be costly to you.)

It would make sense to use blockchain and smrt contract if you are going to come up with an economic model and your users going to actively participate in it by exchanging ETH or tokens. And if you want to keep incoming user request details (transaction calling your contract functions in this case) untampered for future references and verification, using blockchain would be ideal.